# Customized Rating bar 

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

The inbuilt rating bar is too big for my application . How can i reduce its height & width?
Also the color of the stars should be orange & not green . How can i achieve it ?

Also can i have the rating bar in vertical next to a image on my screen ? if yes how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first question, I think [that link](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/) is the one what you want to make . also for second, I believe that you can get it by defining in xml.