# How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android

Tags: android

Hello all i need to perform Ratings in my application... SO i need to create custom Ratings bar... Can Anyone Help me in this?

Comment: Some code snippets would be useful (maybe mockups of your goal), to see where you are so far. Looking at your post it doesn't feel like a problem to solve, more a job offer, please elaborate on that.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

styles.xml

This must be located in your values folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
       <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/food_rating_bar_full</item>
       <item name="android:minHeight">23dip</item>
       <item name="android:maxHeight">25dip</item>
   </style>
  </resources>
```

food_rating_bar_full.xml

This file must be in Drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/food_ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/food_ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/food_ratingbar_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

food_ratingbar_full_empty.xml

This file must be inside Drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- This is the rating bar drawable that is used to
 show a filled cookie. -->
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/cookiee" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/cookiee" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/cookiee" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/cookiee" />

</selector>
```

food_ratingbar_full_filled.xml

This file must be located in Drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <!-- This is the rating bar drawable that is used to
 show a unfilled cookie. -->
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/cookie" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/cookie" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/cookie" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/cookie" />

</selector>
```

main.xml file should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        style="@style/foodRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
    </RatingBar>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.class should look like :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

RatingBar rb;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    rb=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    
    rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Float.toString(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            
        }
        
    }); 
}
}
```

I have used two images:

cookie.jpg

cookiee.jpg

This two images are of same size one is used for identifying selected Rating Bar and other for identifying unselected RatingBar

Comment: i am not able to use the custom style that i create like       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/food_ratingbar_full</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>   when i use it like this <RatingBar   android:id="@+id/my_rating_bar"
            ...
            style="@style/foodRatingBar" />   then it is giving me error

Comment: After specifying my own custom style when i use it in my main.xml like style="@style/hotel_rating_bar_indicator" then it shows that Couldn't resolve resource @style/hotel_rating_bar_indicator.....

Comment: The problem with this is hardcoding the star size height to 23dp. I need the stars to resize based on the layout, like ImageView does

Comment: This worked for me, after changing in the file food_rating_bar_full.xml, the item id's. I replaced <item android:id="@+android:id/background" with <item android:id="@android:id/background" (without the + symbol).

Comment: Shows only tops of stars. Changing in style android:minHeight and maxHeight to 50dp fixed a result.

Comment: fist link in post is down

Comment: Link is not working  http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/

Comment: This isn't working for me. I can only see filled rating bar even after changing rating.

Comment: Yeah @android:id/background, etc. and 50dip size in style are crucial

Comment: the same as @erdomester suggested but more code. *CAUTION: Don't forget that it's not working with Vector Images, only with .png!*

Comment: Didn't work for me, but it was fine when I have replaced: 
- android:id="@+id/background with @android:id/background 
- android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress" with android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
- android:id="@+id/progress" with android:id="@android:id/progress"

Comment: The `<selector>` is useless.

Answer (score 62):

I need to add my solution which is WAY eaiser than the one above. We don't even need to use styles.

Create a selector file in the drawable folder:

custom_ratingbar_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

 <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

 <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_on" />

</layer-list>
```

In the layout set the selector file as progressDrawable:

```
 <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_selector"
        android:numStars="8"
        android:stepSize="0.2"
        android:rating="3.0" />
```

And that's all we need.

Comment: +1, but sorry, this should be working, but its not. First, you said you add the Selector, but in fact you add a layer-list. Second, i tried your code exactly, but all i get is a blank component (no image at all). Maybe you can answer my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251092/custom-rating-bar-not-showing-any-image
Thanks :D

Comment: This simple approach results in problems positioning the rating bar in a layout. A more traditional approach with defining a style is better.

Comment: it is showing a line below at all stars of rating bar

Comment: Works great, thx. *CAUTION:* Don't forget that it's not working with Vector Images, only with .png!

Comment: Thanks! For SVG see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53589663/2914140.

Answer (score 50):

first add images to drawable:

[image] [image]

the first picture "ratingbar_staroff.png" and the second "ratingbar_staron.png"

After, create "ratingbar.xml" on res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

the next xml the same on res/drawable

"ratingbar_empty.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff" />

</selector>
```

"ratingbar_filled"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron" />

</selector>
```

the next to do, add these lines of code on res/values/styles

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">18dp</item>
</style>
```

Now, already can add style to ratingbar resource

```
        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style= "@style/CustomRatingBar"
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="0.01"
            android:isIndicator="true"/>
```

finally on your activity only is declare:

```
RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
ratingbar.setRating(3.67f);
```

[image]

Comment: It is similar to the checked answer. But has pictures (shows fractional stars) and <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection --> in layer-list. You can instead delete a plus sign in "@+android:id/background" to avoid android errors. Also should change minHeight and maxHeight to 50dp.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. may i know how do you adjust the size of the stars? mine come up very small. thx.

Comment: @jay in the `res/values/styles` he is defining `android:minHeight` and `android:maxHeight` change that to make star size big

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!

Answer (score 14):

For **SVG** `RatingBar` I used [RatingBar custom Vector Drawables superimposing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001823/ratingbar-custom-vector-drawables-superimposing) and the answer of [erdomester](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107765/2914140) here. This solution traverses all drawables inside `SvgRatingBar` view of your layout, so in `RecyclerView` it has an overhead.

SvgRatingBar.java:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RoundRectShape;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;

import androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;
import androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat;

import com.example.R; // Your R.java file for R.attr.ratingBarStyle.

public class SvgRatingBar extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRatingBar {

    private Bitmap sampleTile;

    public SvgRatingBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SvgRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.ratingBarStyle);
    }

    public SvgRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) createTile(getProgressDrawable(), false);
        setProgressDrawable(drawable);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a drawable to a tiled version of itself. It will recursively
     * traverse layer and state list drawables.
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private Drawable createTile(Drawable drawable, boolean clip) {
        if (drawable instanceof DrawableWrapper) {
            Drawable inner = ((DrawableWrapper) drawable).getWrappedDrawable();
            if (inner != null) {
                inner = createTile(inner, clip);
                ((DrawableWrapper) drawable).setWrappedDrawable(inner);
            }
        } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
            LayerDrawable background = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
            final int n = background.getNumberOfLayers();
            Drawable[] outDrawables = new Drawable[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int id = background.getId(i);
                outDrawables[i] = createTile(background.getDrawable(i),
                        (id == android.R.id.progress || id == android.R.id.secondaryProgress));
            }
            LayerDrawable newBg = new LayerDrawable(outDrawables);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                newBg.setId(i, background.getId(i));
            }

            return newBg;

        } else if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            final Bitmap tileBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            if (sampleTile == null) {
                sampleTile = tileBitmap;
            }

            final ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(getDrawableShape());
            final BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(tileBitmap,
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(bitmapShader);
            shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColorFilter(bitmapDrawable.getPaint().getColorFilter());
            return (clip) ? new ClipDrawable(shapeDrawable, Gravity.START,
                    ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL) : shapeDrawable;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
            return createTile(getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(drawable), clip);
        } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawableCompat) {
            // API 19 support.
            return createTile(getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(drawable), clip);
        }
        return drawable;
    }

    private BitmapDrawable getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (sampleTile != null) {
            final int width = sampleTile.getWidth() * getNumStars();
            setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState(width, widthMeasureSpec, 0),
                    getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    private Shape getDrawableShape() {
        final float[] roundedCorners = new float[]{5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};
        return new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null, null);
    }
}
```

In your layout:

```
<com.example.common.control.SvgRatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="13dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating_bar"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="0.01"
    />
```

You also have to create rating_bar.xml with two SVG drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unfilled_star"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unfilled_star"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_filled_star"
        />

</layer-list>
```

[image]

If you see in Design/Split view only one star, refresh layout:

[image]

In Kotlin.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapShader
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Shader
import android.graphics.drawable.*
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RoundRectShape
import android.os.Build
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.Gravity
import androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
import androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat
import com.example.R; // Your R.java file for R.attr.ratingBarStyle.

class SvgRatingBar @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                                             defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.ratingBarStyle) :
    AppCompatRatingBar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var sampleTile: Bitmap? = null
    private val roundedCorners = floatArrayOf(5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f)
    private val roundRectShape = RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null, null)

    init {
        progressDrawable = createTile(progressDrawable, false) as LayerDrawable
    }

    /**
     * Converts a drawable to a tiled version of itself. It will recursively
     * traverse layer and state list drawables.
     */
    private fun createTile(drawable: Drawable, clip: Boolean): Drawable =
        when {
            drawable is DrawableWrapper -> {
                @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                var inner = drawable.wrappedDrawable
                if (inner != null) {
                    inner = createTile(inner, clip)
                    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                    drawable.wrappedDrawable = inner
                }
                drawable
            }
            drawable is LayerDrawable -> {
                val n = drawable.numberOfLayers
                val outDrawables = arrayOfNulls<Drawable>(n)
                for (i in 0 until n) {
                    val id = drawable.getId(i)
                    outDrawables[i] = createTile(drawable.getDrawable(i),
                        id == android.R.id.progress || id == android.R.id.secondaryProgress)
                }
                val newBg = LayerDrawable(outDrawables)
                for (i in 0 until n) {
                    newBg.setId(i, drawable.getId(i))
                }
                newBg
            }
            drawable is BitmapDrawable -> {
                val tileBitmap = drawable.bitmap
                if (sampleTile == null) {
                    sampleTile = tileBitmap
                }
                val bitmapShader = BitmapShader(tileBitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
                val shapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable(roundRectShape).apply {
                    paint.shader = bitmapShader
                    paint.colorFilter = drawable.paint.colorFilter
                }
                if (clip) ClipDrawable(shapeDrawable, Gravity.START, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL)
                else shapeDrawable
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && drawable is VectorDrawable -> {
                createTile(getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(drawable), clip)
            }
            drawable is VectorDrawableCompat -> {
                // Pre-Lollipop support.
                createTile(getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(drawable), clip)
            }
            else -> drawable
        }

    private fun getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(drawable: Drawable): BitmapDrawable {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
    }

    @Synchronized override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        if (sampleTile != null) {
            val width = sampleTile!!.width * numStars
            setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState(width, widthMeasureSpec, 0),
                measuredHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works for me.
But need to adjust a bit on the Kotlin constructor.

Comment: @Nguyen, thank you! If you wish, you can change this code, I will be glad to see new things. :)

Comment: Import `DrawableWrapper` not found

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko, agree. Maybe `import androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperCompat`?

Comment: Wrapper code: [github](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-support-library/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper.java)

Comment: or try to use `drawable.drawable` instead of `drawable.wrappedDrawable`

Answer (score 7):

Making the custom rating bar with layer list and selectors is complex, it is better to override the RatingBar class and create a custom RatingBar. createBackgroundDrawableShape() is the function where you should put your empty state png and createProgressDrawableShape() is the function where you should put your filled state png.

Note: This code will not work with svg for now.

```
public class CustomRatingBar extends RatingBar {

    @Nullable
    private Bitmap mSampleTile;

    public ShapeDrawableRatingBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setProgressDrawable(createProgressDrawable());
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSampleTile != null) {
            final int width = mSampleTile.getWidth() * getNumStars();
            setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState(width, widthMeasureSpec, 0), getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    protected LayerDrawable createProgressDrawable() {
        final Drawable backgroundDrawable = createBackgroundDrawableShape();
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{
            backgroundDrawable,
            backgroundDrawable,
            createProgressDrawableShape()
        });

        layerDrawable.setId(0, android.R.id.background);
        layerDrawable.setId(1, android.R.id.secondaryProgress);
        layerDrawable.setId(2, android.R.id.progress);
        return layerDrawable;
    }

    protected Drawable createBackgroundDrawableShape() {
        final Bitmap tileBitmap = drawableToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_empty));
        if (mSampleTile == null) {
            mSampleTile = tileBitmap;
        }
        final ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(getDrawableShape());
        final BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(tileBitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(bitmapShader);
        return shapeDrawable;
    }

    protected Drawable createProgressDrawableShape() {
        final Bitmap tileBitmap = drawableToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_full));
        final ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(getDrawableShape());
        final BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(tileBitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(bitmapShader);
        return new ClipDrawable(shapeDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    }

    Shape getDrawableShape() {
        final float[] roundedCorners = new float[]{5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};
        return new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null, null);
    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        width = width > 0 ? width : 1;
        int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can increase the space beetween items?

Comment: @AliRezaiyan: Since we are using our own drawables i.e. ic_star_full and ic_star_empty, you can simply add empty space (padding) to the left and right sides of your PNG. You can use tools like GIMP or Android Asset Studio to achieve this by editing your PNG.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm looking for a programmatically way

Answer (score 6):

I investigated the original source,
and here is my result.

**styles.xml** (res/values)

```
<!-- RatingBar -->
<style name="RatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">13.4dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">13.4dp</item>
</style>
```

**ratingbar_full.xml** (res/drawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_rating_star_off_normal" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_rating_star_off_normal" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_rating_star_on_normal" />
</layer-list>
```

**btn_rating_star_off_normal.png** (res/drawable-xxhdpi)

[image]

**btn_rating_star_on_normal.png** (res/drawable-xxhdpi)

[image]

**activity_ratingbar.xml** (res/layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        style="@style/RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="13.4dp"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="2.6"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="#00000000"
        android:stepSize="0.1" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**This is the result.**

[image]

- Note that I added the actual height(13.4dp) of ratingbar in `layout_height` property, because if it is `wrap_content` it will draw lines below stars. (in my case only in a preview of Android Studio)

Comment: Why the uploaded images were in gif format instead of png.

Comment: @taranjeetsapra I'm not sure why it's gif format, I have no idea now since I posted it long times ago.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this rating bar with much better animations

[SmileyRating](https://github.com/sujithkanna/SmileyRating)

[image]

Comment: Icon click listener not working, even after setting the setIndicator(false).

Answer (score 3):

I made something simular, a RatingBar with individual rating icons, I'm using VectorDrawables for the rating icons but you could use any type of drawable

https://github.com/manmountain/emoji-ratingbar

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following code works:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    int stars = getNumStars();
    float rating = getRating();
    try
    {
        bitmapWidth = getWidth() / stars;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        bitmapWidth = getWidth();
    }
    float x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stars; i++)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Resources res = getResources();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        if ((int) rating > i)
        {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, starColor);
        }
        else
        {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, starDefault);
        }
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, getHeight(), getHeight(), true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, x, 0, paint);
        canvas.save();
        x += bitmapWidth;
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom material rating bar by defining drawable xml using material icon of your choice and then applying custom drawable to rating bar using 
progressDrawable attribute.

For infomration about customizing rating bar see 
http://www.zoftino.com/android-ratingbar-and-custom-ratingbar-example

Below drawable xml uses thumbs up icon for rating bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/thumb_up"
            android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/thumb_up"
            android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/thumb_up"
            android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a custom rating bar that displays a solid gradient line running on a SeekBar-like track, rather than stars, I also encountered a problem related to the vertical centering of the background (track drawable).  This is the flawed drawable code I used originally (which generated the problem), as suggested by Android developer and other StackOverflow entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_track"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress2"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" >
        <clip android:clipOrientation="horizontal" android:gravity="left" >
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/ratingbar_bg_start"
                    android:centerColor="@color/ratingbar_bg_center"
                    android:centerX="0.5"
                    android:endColor="@color/ratingbar_bg_end"
                    android:angle="0"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>    

 </layer-list>
```

The problem here is the first item, which relates to the background of the custom RatingBar.  Many entries will tell you to set the layout_minHeight feature to some large value to avoid a vertical spatial disconnect between the thumb and its track.  This was not the solution for me - when viewed on a tablet, the background was still drawing to its smaller phone-based size - so the track was consistently positioned well above the center of the RatingBar track.  The solution is to remove this entry in the RatingBar drawable, so it now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress2"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" >
        <clip android:clipOrientation="horizontal" android:gravity="left" >
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/ratingbar_bg_start"
                    android:centerColor="@color/ratingbar_bg_center"
                    android:centerX="0.5"
                    android:endColor="@color/ratingbar_bg_end"
                    android:angle="0"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>    

 </layer-list>
```

Then, in the style definition of the custom RatingBar, set the layout_background to the the track drawable.  Mine looks like this:

```
<style name="styleRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/seekbar_track</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/abratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/abseekbar_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/base_29dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/base_29dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/base_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/base_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/base_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/base_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
</style>
```

(Previously, the background setting here was undefined.).

This is the entry in my layout, which uses both the style and the drawables:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingbar_vote"
    style="@style/styleRatingBar"
    android:hint="@string/ratingbar_vote"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ratingbar_vote"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/base_29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/base_120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />
```

So, to summarize, do not set the background (track) feature in your custom RatingBar drawable, set it in the layout_background feature of your custom RatingBar style.  This ensures the track is always vertically centered in a horizontal RatingBar.  (Remember, in this custom RatingBar, instead of using stars or other isolated images as the rating, I'm using a gradient line that "grows" or "shrinks" horizontally to display the rating - this rating line uses a SeekBar-like thumb running on a SeekBar-like "track".)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @erdomester 's given solution for this. But if you are facing issues with rating bar height then you can use ratingbar's icons height programmatically.

In Kotlin,

```
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.rating_filled)
val drawableHeight = drawable.intrinsicHeight

rating_bar.layoutParams.height = drawableHeight
```

Comment: I also faced this issue, but added `android:minHeight` in layout. If change programmatically, you should add `rating_bar.requestLayout()`.

Answer (score 0):

### A different approach (in Progress)

##### Just for fun:

**Pros:** Supports `SVG`, responsive, easy implementation, light, customizable, etc

**Cons:** just supports integer ratings (average rating must be integer)

[image]

```
<style name="RatingButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.Icon">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/selector_text_color</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">textTop</item>
    <item name="iconPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="iconSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetLeft">0dp</item>
    <!--<item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>-->
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetRight">0dp</item>
</style>


<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
                android:id="@+id/ratingToggleGroup"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:singleSelection="false">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/ratingButton1"
                    style="@style/RatingButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:icon="@drawable/ic_star_rounded_fill" />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/ratingButton2"
                    style="@style/RatingButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:icon="@drawable/ic_star_rounded_fill" />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/ratingButton3"
                    style="@style/RatingButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:icon="@drawable/ic_star_rounded_fill" />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/ratingButton4"
                    style="@style/RatingButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:icon="@drawable/ic_star_rounded_fill" />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/ratingButton5"
                    style="@style/RatingButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:icon="@drawable/ic_star_rounded_fill" />

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>


void showRatingBar(MaterialButton mButton1, 
                  MaterialButton mButton2,
                  MaterialButton mButton3,
                  MaterialButton mButton4,
                  MaterialButton mButton5){
       
       
       mButton5.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           if(mButton4.isChecked()){
               mButton5.setChecked(true);
           }
           mButton4.setChecked(false);
           mButton3.setChecked(false);
           mButton2.setChecked(false);
           mButton1.setChecked(false);
       });


       mButton4.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           if(mButton3.isChecked()){
               mButton4.setChecked(true);
           }
           mButton5.setChecked(true);
           mButton3.setChecked(false);
           mButton2.setChecked(false);
           mButton1.setChecked(false);
       });

       mButton3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           if(mButton2.isChecked()){
               mButton3.setChecked(true);
           }
           mButton5.setChecked(true);
           mButton4.setChecked(true);
           mButton2.setChecked(false);
           mButton1.setChecked(false);
       });
       mButton2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           if(mButton1.isChecked()){
               mButton2.setChecked(true);
           }
           mButton5.setChecked(true);
           mButton4.setChecked(true);
           mButton3.setChecked(true);
           mButton1.setChecked(false);
       });
       mButton1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           mButton5.setChecked(true);
           mButton4.setChecked(true);
           mButton3.setChecked(true);
           mButton2.setChecked(true);
       });
   }
```

Answer (score -11):

You can have 5 imageview with defalut image as star that is empty and fill the rating bar with half or full image base on rating.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View grid=inflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem, parent, false);
     imageView=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_prod);
     imageView.setImageResource(imgId[position]);
     imgoff =(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.offer);
     tv=(TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
     tv.setText(namesArr[position]);
     tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     tv.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 0);
   sta=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    sta1=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    sta2=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    sta3=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    sta4=(ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    Float rate=rateFArr[position];


   if(rate==5 || rate==4.5)
    {
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        if(rate==4.5)
        {
            sta4.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);
        }
        else
        {
            sta4.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        }
    }
    if(rate==4 || rate==3.5)
    {
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
     if(rate==3.5)
        {
            sta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);
        }
        else
        {
            sta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        }
    }
    if(rate==3 || rate==2.5)
    {
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
       if(rate==2.5)
        {
            sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);
        }
        else
        {
            sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        }
    }
    if(rate==2 || rate==1.5)
    {
    sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
     if(rate==1.5)
        {
            sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);
        }
        else
        {
            sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        }
    }
    if(rate==1 || rate==0.5)
    {
        if(rate==1)
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        else
            sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_small);

    }
    if(rate>5)
    {
        sta.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
        sta4.setImageResource(R.drawable.full__small);
    }

    // rb=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.grid_rating);
     //rb.setRating(rateFArr[position]);
        return grid;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't the way to do this. For do this things is the `RatingBar` widget. Also this isn't what the OP asks.