# Problem with custom rating bar in android

Tags: android

I implemented customized rating bar as explained here

[How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

but when I try to make the minHeight of the rating bar<23 I always get this result

[image: wrong]

while I wanna make a rating bar with this size 
[image]

do I have to resize the images I use in drawable according to the rating bar max and min heights or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem maybe be related to the sreen resolution. Try to add this on your manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.main" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
...
```

More info here: http://www.jdamcd.com/?p=303

And you can also try setting `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall`

Comment: do I set the style this in the main or what? I really don't get it :(

Comment: You should put this on your AndroidManifest.xml: `<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
`
And if you want, o can try to set `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall` on your layout xml file.

Comment: no the support-screens tag didn't affect my program so Iam asking about style="?android:attr<--I don't get this so I'm asking where to put it?

Comment: Example: `<RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingBar" style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RatingBar>`

Comment: can I control the width of the rating bar or the space between each star in this built-in rating bar I used or in the other rating bar I made before?