# Customizing rating bar in android

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I have to design a custon list item including rating bar in it

I followed this tutorial([[Problem with custom rating bar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351053/problem-with-custom-rating-bar-in-android][2])) for customising and resizing rating bar.Rating bar is now appering small bt i am unable to click on it

My custom listItem Code is :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:stretchColumns="*" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tbl">
    <TableRow>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" />
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Item Name" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_width="100dp" android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Price" />
            <TextView android:layout_width="100dp" android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Discount" />
            <TextView android:layout_width="100dp" android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="In Stock" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingBar1" android:fitsSystemWindows="false" 
                android:maxWidth="150dip" android:minHeight="23dip" android:maxHeight="25dip" 
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="150dp" /> -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Shipping days" />
            <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingBar" style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:focusable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RatingBar>
            <Button android:layout_width="60dip" android:layout_height="35dip"
                android:text="Buy" android:textSize="15dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And the screenShot is : [image]

EDIT :

i developed the customized rating bar but now whatever i set the rating in landscape and when i look at the application in portrait whole rating bars are deselected..what to do to keep rating bar selected ?

Comment: The rating bar with style `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
` is not user intractable. Have a look at [Pretty RatingBar](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/)

Comment: Thanx Adil Soomro.That tutorial is awesome ,customized my rating bar :)

Comment: @AdilSoomro agree with Adil, its not user interactable.

Comment: Have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android/5800686#14327733

Answer (score 3):

The smaller RatingBar style ( ratingBarStyleSmall) and the larger indicator-only style (ratingBarStyleIndicator) do not support user interaction and should only be used as indicators.
(from [RatingBar manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html))

Answer (score 1):

Use drawables with different sizes for `HDPI` and `MDPI`, and then give your ratingbar a specific height in `dp`. Or, put one empty row of pixels in your drawable. but the second way just solves the look of your ratingbars, and the height will be wrong. I suggest the first way.