# How to use Rating bar?

Tags: android, textview, rating

i would like to save the state of rating bar rating stars? How would i go about doing this?
and also how would i go about getting the number of stars the user has selected? To display in a textView?
Thanks

Comment: Try the the official [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html).

Answer (score 0):

From developer.android.com :

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RatingBar

Other Example Here..

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/02/ratingbar.html

If you want to customize RatingBar eg. Displaying other image than default Star
refer [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android/5800686#5800686)

This example shows `Toast` message when user selects Ratings. 
& Obviously you will have to customize it according to  your needs (as you told you want to display it in TextView).

You can define a `TextView` in xml file & set its text property when Rating has changed.