# Is it possible to change the RatingBar direction?

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone knows if its possible to make the RatingBar go from right-to-Left instead of left to right, or have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to customize the `RatingBar`..

However you just have to play tricks with displaying `RatingBar` Images & then some sort of reverse calculations.

Trick will be displaying reverse Images in RatingBar.. swap selected and unselected images in RatingBar.

Allow user to rate on `RatingBar`. You have to swap selected and unselected calculations. I mean you have to do reverse calculations.

Complete Working example of custom `RatingBar` on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android/5800686#5800686) answered by me only.

Download `RatingBar` icons from here : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use `android:rotation="180"` in your Ratingbar to rotate it 
i used this way on my read-only Ratingbars, i dont know if this will effect interacting with the Ratingbar.

Comment: then you also should rotate drawables in graphics editor which is not easier then just to set reverse amount of stars

Answer (score 5):

Use attribute `android:scaleX="-1"`

OR

```
package com.example.selection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class InvertRatingBar extends RatingBar {

    public InvertRatingBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InvertRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InvertRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
        event.setLocation(width - event.getX(), event.getY());
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
        Matrix matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
        matrix.preTranslate(width, 0);  
        matrix.preScale(-1.f, 1);
        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```