# How to insert ImageView at the end of multiline TextView?

Tags: android, interface, textview, imageview

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I cant find a way to inser small image at the end of second line of TextView. Image is always appears to the right of whole textview, not the line end.

I want to insert image like this:

```
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextText. <ImageView>
```

What I am getting is:

```
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText  <ImageView>
TextTextTextText.
```

I hope there is way to do it.

Src:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTES"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Give your xml code, easier to see the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

create an ImageSpan and add it to your textview. This way, you can put your image where you want in the text

Example -

```
ImageSpan imagespan = new ImageSpan(appContext, ressource); 
text.setSpan(imagespan, i, i+ strLength, 0); //text is an object of TextView
```

Comment: ImageSpan imagespan = new ImageSpan(appContext, ressource);
text.setSpan(imagespan, i, i+ strLength, 0);

Comment: try creating many spans and concatenate them using TextUtils.concat()

Comment: There is no TextView.setSpan method.

Comment: @DiscDev because you are trying to apply setSpan to a TextView instead of a Spannable

Comment: @erdomester yup.  The comment in the OP's post says "text is an object of TextView" ...obviously it's not because that wouldn't compile.

Comment: SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(title);
                                    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gallery_list);
                                    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                                    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                                    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                                    newsTextView.setText(ss);

Comment: @BudaGavril After using this solution setOnTouchListener for textview drawable will not work !

Answer (score 5):

One best way to complete it is as the following...

```
ImageGetter getter = new ImageGetter(){                 
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source){   // source is the resource name
        Drawable d = null;
        Integer id =  new Integer(0);
        id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", "com.sampleproject");

        d = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(id);   

        if (d != null)
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

        return d;
    }
};

String imgString = this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_string) + " <img src=\"img_drawable_image\"/>";
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_id)).setText(
Html.fromHtml(imgString, getter, null));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the image to end of the string without using imageview like below;

```
fun addImageToEndOfTheString(text: String, drawableResourceId : Int ,context: Context) : SpannableStringBuilder {
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableResourceId)!!
    drawable.setBounds(14, 0, 64, 50)
    val rocketImageSpan = ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)

    val ssBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(text)

    ssBuilder.setSpan(
        rocketImageSpan,
        text.length - 1,
        text.length,
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )

    return ssBuilder
}
```

and call it like;

```
textView.text = addImageToEndOfTheString("Your text is here", R.drawable.ic_your_image, context!!)
```

[image: The image will placed end of the text]

Comment: How can we make the imageview clickable? I mean is there a way to setOnClickListener for this image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32063821/3341089 you may use ClickableSpan like in this link which is answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(title);
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gallery_list);
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
newsTextView.setText(ss);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView textView =new TextView(this);
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder( "Here's a smiley how are you " );
Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.movie_add );
ssb.setSpan( new ImageSpan( smiley ), ssb.length()-1,  ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );  
textView.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert Drawable at the end of the text, Drawable is hiding the last character of the text to avoid that add another character at the end of the text and start the drawable at that character.

```
val myText = "Your text"    

val span: Spannable = SpannableString(myText+"-")
val android: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.yourDrawable)!!
android.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30)
val image = ImageSpan(android, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM)
span.setSpan(image, span.indexOf("-"), span.indexOf("-")+1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin extension on the `TextView` class

```
/**
 * Creates a StringSpan using the text from the TextView itself and it also adds an ImageSpan at the
 * end of the last line of the TextView.
 * This basically allows us to set a drawable at the end of the TextView text.
 */
fun TextView.setImageSpanAtTheEnd(context: Context, @DrawableRes drawableRes: Int) {
    text = SpannableString("$text ").apply {
        val d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableRes) ?: throw RuntimeException("Drawable not found!")
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.intrinsicWidth, d.intrinsicHeight)
        setSpan(ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), text.length, text.length+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
    }
}
```

Just call it *after* you set the text on the `TextView` and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the best solution, but you can try using [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler%29) to insert image into your line.

```
ImageGetter getter = new ImageGetter(){                 
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source){
        Drawable d = null;

        context.getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(source));   

        if (d != null)
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

        return d;
    }
};
String imgString = <source string> + " <img src=\"R.drawable.icon\"/>";
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(
    Html.fromHtml(imgString, getter, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Libin Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38119111/2914140) I created a solution for `RatingBar`. I used [`SvgRatingBar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53589663/2914140) with SVG stars.

`ImageSpan` extends `DynamicDrawableSpan`, and `DynamicDrawableSpan` has only one child - `ImageSpan`. So, to attach another `View` to the end of the `TextView` we should get a drawable made from the `View`. I added a method `getDrawable()` to `SvgRatingBar`:

```
public class SvgRatingBar extends AppCompatRatingBar {

    ...
    private Drawable drawable;

    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
    }

    private void init() {
        LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) createTile(getProgressDrawable(), false);
        setProgressDrawable(drawable);
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }
```

Create a layout for the rating (layout_rating_bar.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.myapplication.SvgRatingBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:minHeight="13dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating_bar"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="0.01" />
```

Then write this code:

```
val inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
val ratingBar: SvgRatingBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_rating_bar, null, false)
    as SvgRatingBar
ratingBar.rating = 3.5f
val drawable = ratingBar.drawable

val ss = SpannableString("dsfjdskljsf dsfjsdkljfslk dsfjlksdjflsdkjf ")
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 170, 30) // Set width and height of the rating bar here.
val span = ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)
ss.setSpan(span, ss.length - 1, ss.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
textView.setText(ss)
```

[image]