# Android. How to insert image in text

Tags: android

Actually I have TextView with some text. I need to insert an image insight this text. Please suggest the best way to do that. Should be supported on different display sizes.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913987/how-to-insert-imageview-at-the-end-of-multiline-textview

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about to display image inside the TextView at either Top/Bottom/Right/Left side, if yes then:

```
<TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World, DemoExampleActivity!"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dip"/>
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image as the background for the `TextView` like this:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text to be displayed"
    android:background ="@drawable/your_image"
    />
```

Good luck,
Arkde

Answer (score 0):

If want to do it via xml

add this attribute to TextView element

```
android:background="@drawable/icon"
```

If at runtime programatically

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

            or

    tv..setBackgroundResource(resid);
```