# Smaller ratings bar

Tags: android

I've been through all of these forums looking for an answers on how to change the size of the ratings bar (making the stars smaller) and im not really sure if it can be done? I saw the tutorial with the "custom pretty ratings bar" but i'm not really trying to create anything new. I want to use the stars that the packages come with. I want a 10 star rating where all stars fit on the screen, right now only about 7 fit on the screen. Basically I want it to look like the IMDB app. rating system if anyone has seen that? Thanks for the help. I'll paste some code but it's not a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to make your own custom star drawables. Even if they are just copies of the system star drawable that are shrunk down.

Comment: I do agree with FoamyGuy since 10 System star are so big to be fitted  in the Activity main contentView

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create your custom style for the rating bar.

Here it is well explained:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800686/435855