# Small Style Custom rating bar (readonly custom rating bar)

Tags: android, custom-component, ratingbar

I tried to create a custom rating bar. I don't use `style` because I only use this once. So, I created a `layer-list` in the `drawable` folder (its name is `custom_rating_bar.xml`):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/custom_icon_empty"/>
  <item
    android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/custom_icon_empty"/>
  <item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/custom_icon"/>
</layer-list>
```

And I use this code in the rating bar to use those icons:

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_rating_bar"
```

My image size is standard (48x48 for mdpi, etc) and i use a **small** style rating bar :

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

The problem is, i cant use `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"` together with `android:progressDrawable` (When i did this, the images will not shown). When i delete the style (`style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`) my rating bar become too big (the images are shown).

This image show how big is it (i think the **margin** between image is also too much) :
[image]

So, **how to make my custom rating bar smaller?** (as small as the default small style rating bar).

And this custom rating bar is **for show only** (cant be changed by user).

Thanks.

Comment: If you want this rating bar for show only, set this: ``android:isIndicator="true"``

Answer (score 3):

First off, remove the "+"s from your android:id. Also, you may want to add a style in your xml, such as `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` depending on your needs. You might also need to use `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_rating_bar"` instead of progressDrawable

Comment: Thanks :D, sorry i dont know what is the relation of progressBar and rating bar?:D

Comment: @BlazeTama, oh yeah I was confused too. Didn't catch that this was a rating bar. Is that what you want or you want a progress bar? the progressDrawable attribute in a ratingbar is undefined...

Comment: @BlazeTama actually I see they do have progressDrawables

Comment: I want to make a small custom rating bar. How to define it? Thanks :D

Comment: @BlazeTama, lets solve one problem at a time. Did removing the "+"s fix anything?

Comment: Also, you're gonna have to set the min and max height on your ratingbar to match the size of the asset. otherwise, things wont look right.

Comment: The images shown when i remove the small style (style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall") and the '+'.But the rating bar become to big (i want the small one, as small as the small style). Do you have any idea how to do this? Thanks :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22497/discussion-between-blaze-tama-and-luxurymode)

Comment: If the ratingbar is just for show, why not just use an imageview with something that looks like a rating bar created by you as an asset?

Comment: I cant do that, because even the user cant interact with the rating bar, i still need to change the value of it :D

Comment: As far as I know you can't make the ratingbar smaller in code. You need to create smaller images for the rating bar. Last time when I created a custom rating bar, this was the only way to go for me.