# Custom Image Rating Bar - secondaryProgress and Progress drawables are superposing, help me ! (code and hypothesis included)

Tags: android, ratingbar

**EDIT:**  I removed the line

```
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_full_empty_sc"/>
```

and it cancels the poor efect. so it is indeed a superpostion issue. Now the feeling is very clumsy to give half rating. Anyone has a real solution? Please...

**Original Post**

I try to implement a rating bar but I have some issue with the half filled ones. I modify existing code and follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

Here is the strange result :

[image: Rating Bar - note the darker stroke around the half-filled star]

ever heard of that problem?

I am posting my code below

```
 <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating_view"
            style="@style/sc_rating_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_medium" />
```

style of the rating bar :

```
    <style name="sc_rating_bar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full_sc</item>
    </style>
```

progressDrawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_full_empty_sc"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_full_empty_sc"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_full_filled_sc"/>

</layer-list>
```

ratingbar_full_empty_sc :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty2" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty2" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty2" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty2"/>

</selector>
```

and his brother, ratingbar_full_filled_sc is exactly the same with `star_full2` image.

What did I do wrong ? You can see both pictures on my screenshot, full fill star and empty one.

Answer (score 0):

Ahah ! I found a small solution, based on my previous edit : in the `progressDrawable` I modify the `secondaryProgress` into

```
    <item
    android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_full_null_sc"/>
```

And as the name indicates I put an empty image as drawable inside :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty2_null" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty2_null" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty2_null" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty2_null"/>

</selector>
```

The `@drawable/star_empty2_null` refers to an image, same size as the fill star and empty star, but with nothing in it (I took the star file, clear it in Gimp and export it with same pixel size).

**Perfectly smooth animation, no more visual superposition!**