# Drawables do not fit android custom rating bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have a problem with a custom rating bar. I have followed the instructions of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

to create my custom rating bar and the mechanic works but I have a glitch on the end of my bar : [here is a picture]

[image: [2]].

The background and the progressDrawable do not seem to fit right. I really don't have a clue where the problem could come from.
I thought I had the beginning of an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289081/custom-image-rating-bar-secondaryprogress-and-progress-drawables-are-superposi) but since I didn't use a secondary progressDrawable it didn't help me.

**EDIT :**

As asked here are the XML files I use. Nothing is done programmatically :

values/style.xml

```
<style name="UserRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/user_rating_stars</item>
</style>
```

drawable/user_rating_stars.xml :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/user_rating_bar_empty"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/user_rating_bar_full"/>
</layer-list>
```

drawable/user_rating_bar_empty :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_normal" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_normal" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_normal" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_normal"/>
</selector>
```

drawable/user_rating_bar_full :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_active" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_active" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_active" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_active"/>
</selector>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I too built a custom rating bar. You can have a peak in my code to see if you can spot your problem https://github.com/kanytu/custom-rating-bar

Comment: What's the "glitch"?

Comment: If you zoom on the red rectangle, you'll see that the active star is not exactly over the inactive star in the background. @PedroOliveira thanks for the sample code ! :)

Comment: I suggest you update your question and add some code so we can check what's going on.

Comment: @PedroOliveira I added the code snippets used for creating the custom rating bar

Comment: @PedroOliveira Is it possible to bypass float values in custom rating bar? I meant is there any way like android:stepSize in custom rating bar??

Comment: @DroidLearner Yes it is possible. I just committed a new version to github. Use the attribute `app:halfStars` to define if you want to work with half stars or not.

Comment: @PedroOliveira Thanks and Works perfect!! and I can't make star to 0 from 5 to 0

Comment: @DroidLearner Yes you're right. That was something I changed for another project. It's fixed already

Comment: @PedroOliveira one more thing, I have ScrollView as parent layout. when scrolls down or up stars gets selected. How to handle this kinda situation??

Comment: @DroidLearner I don't think that's an easy one to solve. I've created a new branch since I haven't tested this 100% and I don't have much time to do it. https://github.com/kanytu/custom-rating-bar/tree/scrollview_fix

Comment: @PedroOliveira oh! Alright. I've tested and it didn't work

Comment: Please post an issue on the repository.