# Ratingbar style in ListView, strange behavior

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-styles, ratingbar

I use custom RatingBar style in ListView row element, but it cause some strange problem.
I have got custom style like this:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/course_rating_bar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">15dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">15dip</item>
</style>
```

And I use this in my RatingBar in xml (in layout of listView row):

```
style="@style/CourseRatingBar"
```

But then the `ListView onItemClickListener` just doesn't work. When I click on element, 
there is no action.

When I use this as my RatingBar style:

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

everything (onItemClickListener ;-)) works fine.

The ListView use BaseAdapter with Holder pattern, with RatingBar, TextView and ImageView.

Comment: Did you find a way to manage this yet? I got into same issue

Comment: @Herious: Check this out- from my expirience it will work if you customize your rating bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my expirience- if this don't work, try to customize your rating bar [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)