# Apply styles to ratingbar in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to apply styles to rating bar in `xamarin.android project`.

I have two images in my drawable folder i.e. `grayStar` and `orangeStar`.

I have referred a solution given in the post

> [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

but my project is returning error i.e

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:progressDrawable' with value '@drawable/DrawableRatingBar'
```

can anyone tell me, where I have done mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Images Build action, sometimes when using Visual studio an images build action can be set to BundleResource. it should be set to AndroidResource

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

The drawable name should be in lowercase, im pretty sure that solves your problem.