# Queries for Android RatingBar customization

Tags: android, rating

I am creating a screen for food review for one of my android application. I know android provides with a default RatingBar control. I just wanted to replace star based rating with emoticon [smilies] or any other custom images. I tried to google for images specific to rating bar and i am not able to find anything relevant. Could anybody point me to a tutorial that helps to develop emoticon rating system? It would also be very helpful for me if anybody could point me to websites from where i could download icons for rating bar in android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

[How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android) This question should be similar to what you're going for. Also you can get icons from https://www.iconfinder.com/ be sure to check the license on the images though.