# Image not changing on custom rating bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

**Firstly this is not a Duplicate of any question**

I have searched lots of questions SO but the could not find answer to my problem
I have used this [Link](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/)  to make custom rating bar in android.that i got from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android) now in this ,when i m doing this the image is not changing.just like its shown [Here](http://kozyr.zydako.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/cookieRatingBar.png)

any help please
as i have to use these kinds of images for my app ,these are cookies and i m using glass (Empty/filled/Halffilled)

thanks :)

Comment: What about posting the relevant code snippets?

Comment: its not changing the image .image is always the same.as the filled cokkie.although the value is showing in the toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem ,And It Was in the PNG files 
they were having some extra spaces in them so i made them proper with Photoshop 
and they are working fine .

Thanks For the people who tries to help me.

Comment: Can you show me the changes you have made in the PNG files. I removed all spaces possible, even tried it with a square image, however, my image still remains static. Doesnt change