# Android: Custom RatingBar - Images do not fit

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, ratingbar

I am having a bit of a problem when setting a custom rating bar in android. I have followed this tutorial:

[How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

However I am experiencing an issue when changing/selecting more than 4 stars. The selected star image is misplaced a bit. Here is an image to show you what it looks like.

[image: Misplaced stars]

Here is my XML for creating the custom rating bar.

Main xml where the rating bar view is defined:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:numStars="50"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            style="@style/AppCustomRatingBar"/>
```

Custom style for the RatingBar

```
<style name="AppCustomRatingBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_stars_custom</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">19dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">19dp</item>
</style>
```

rating_stars_custom.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_stars_yellow_empty" />

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_stars_yellow_empty" />

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_stars_yellow_full" />
```

rating_stars_yellow_empty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_stars_yellow_empty" />

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_stars_yellow_empty" />

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_stars_yellow_full" />
```

rating_stars_yellow_full.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/home_icon_star_fill_selected" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/home_icon_star_fill_selected" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/home_icon_star_fill_selected" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/home_icon_star_fill_selected" />
```

What am I doing wrong to misplace the stars? The image sizes of the stars (both yellow and white) are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it. If you look at the picture I provided in my post above the yellow stars are like off with 1pix compared to empty stars. So I took a look at my pictures I use and their sizes. After that it appeared that the yellow star was 1pix shorter (in width) compared to the image with the empty star. So this was my problem I got new pictures of stars and I made sure they are the same size. Now I have 2 pictures 30x30 and all is OK! This fixed my problem! So my advice for people who are facing the same issue is to take a vary careful look at the size of the pictures they are using (empty/full) and make sure they are the same size. This way you save time and unnecessary coding. GL&HF :)

Answer (score 0):

well I had the same problem with the rating bar. after doing some research I've found a way to overcome the above issue.

- first, you need 2 stars, one empty star and one colored star. and size should be the same. (in my case both are 25x25)

then put this code in styles xml

```
 <style name="redbar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_red</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">25dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">25dip</item>
</style>
```

create another xml file called ratingbar_red.xml inside the drawable folder.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star" />    
</layer-list>
```

Finally crate your RatingBar like this.

```
 <RatingBar
                                android:id="@+id/RatingBar05"
                                style="@style/redbar"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:isIndicator="false"
                                android:numStars="5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

this error || problem is actually related to the sizes of your images, Both have to be in the same size, the way I fixed this err is that I didn't remove the stoke or the border of the filled image, both images must have the same width and height