# I want to make a custom rating bar, but instead of showing same image for each rate icon, i want to show numbers, such as 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

I want to make a custom rating bar, but instead of showing same image for each rate icon, i want to show numbers, such as 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5.
I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android) and [this](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/). So i was able to create Custom Rating bar with same images. But i want different images for different rating.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: instead of this : [image: default],

i want it like 
[image: Green as filled and gray as empty]

Comment: can you add some images?

Comment: And can you add some code?

Comment: @user3676184  Check it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom view by extending `LinearLayout`, and adding 5 `TextViews` into it with gray background. Process clicks on these `TextViews` by setting green background to the `TextViews` to the left of clicked one and to the clicked one. Also save the index of clicked `textView` as current selected rating.

Comment: I wanted to make utilization of Ratingbar instead of using TextView. Is it not possible with rating bar widget?

Comment: Its not possible with rating bar widget

Comment: Thanks !! That was the only question in my mind.. @user3676184. I used Textview as Vlad matvienko suggested.