# custom rating bar drawables not overlapping properly

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

I am creating custom rating bar.The problem is that drawables are not overlaying properly,because there are two different images with same hight and width.It should be like this when the progress will be updated the default image should be replaced by the image2. Any idea?

```
<RatingBar
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customselector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Here is my custom selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />

</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason for downvoting ?

Comment: Hi there, Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: @Sheychan edited the question.

Comment: Damn I wanted to experiment that, ufortunately I am on the process of updating my AS. and my internet slower than a Sea Urchin. did you see this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android

Comment: @Sheychan.Yeap i tried,but not helpful on my case

Comment: One last thing, your gray background drawable seems to be a mirror of the yellow activated rating.. Is this intended? Is it your intention that it is mirrored? because if not, you just have to mirror the drawable using some photoeditting softwares then boom

Comment: yes it is intended.@Sheychan

Comment: In that case, what I can see is you should create an additional selector file in which the other one uses the mirrored/blank drawable when state activated is true, if you know what I mean. . . Still cant code arrrgh

Comment: @Sheychan,tried also with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The way I set the selector to the RatingBar is a bit different, but I don't know if it will help:

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:rating="3"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    style="@style/mileageRatingBar"/>
```

In your values/styles.xml file put this:

```
<style name="mileageRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_stars</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">32dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">32dip</item>
</style>
```

You can of course change the size. And as you can see here is the reference to the custom drawable.

Comment: what is `mileageRatingBar` ?

Comment: That's the name of your selector file. Edited

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android

Comment: what are sizes of image1 & image2 ?

Comment: Second try make height equal wrap_content

Comment: @minafawzy the images are 86*86.height equal wrap_content  doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customselector"
```

and add style in your *values/styles.xml*

to be like this

```
<RatingBar
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
       style="@style/customRatingBar"/>
```

your style from styles.xml

```
<style name="customRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/customselector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">32dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">32dip</item>
</style>
```

the `customselector.xml` file must place in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />

</layer-list>
```

make sure item id is written correctly  , then you  have two option to assign  **drawable** as image or put your selector into your drawable folder  selector.xml with your custom setting

instead of **image1** put **ratingbar_empty.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />

</selector>
```

the same to progress but change selector to image2

Comment: How to use the selector.xml file?