# Android - how to put 5 different Smiley in Rating Bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am creating a form in which i have to put five different smiley icon in rating bar to get feedback from user.

I tried but at a time only one type of icon is being displaying.

I am trying by changing style in style.xml

```
 <style name="customRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
            <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
            <item name="android:minHeight">32dip</item>
            <item name="android:maxHeight">32dip</item>
        </style>
```

Please suggest me how could we achieve this in android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android

Comment: This is very difficult to do within the confines of the standard system `RatingBar` components. Android doesn't cater for 5 different images, rather for 1 image duplicated 5 times. As [Harry suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34053945/383414), make your own with buttons.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a ratingbar which uses **face morphing animation** to animate different smiley reactions.

[image]

[SmileyRating](https://github.com/sujithkanna/SmileyRating) **github**

> You can clearly see that the smiley is changing its reaction slowly.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with RatingBar I would say ditch it completely and implement your own mechanism for getting the feedback. Maybe a horizontal linear layout with 5 circular buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only way I found is to make a LinearLayout with the 5 different faces as elements, and manually control touch position to change faces from selected to unselected, emulating how an old plain android RatingBar works.

I recently made a [library](https://github.com/inlacou/IrisRatingBar) out if this implementation, maybe it can help you.

An example of the library working with faces:

[image: example of library working with faces]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [EmojiRatingBar](https://github.com/unaisulhadi/emojiratingbar) library.
[image]