# The color of Rating Bar Android doesn't match with AppCompat when touch just one of the stars given?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I've searched and tested http://www.javatpoint.com/android-rating-bar-example, http://exandroidstudio.blogspot.co.id/2015/11/rating-bar-material-design-tips.html and some of stackoverflow discussions but cannot solve it. I add a RatingBar and set the style. When I dragged it to another star the color matches with my app color. The problem is when i was touching the star fill color become gray and the border become black. I want to make the ontouch star color matches with my app color theme too. This is my layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/keyline_xs"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="5"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"
                android:stepSize="1.0"
                tools:rating="3.0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe this is a simple thing but I have tried and tested some ways. Any help?
UPDATE: Uploaded Stretched Star Image[image]

Comment: I think, as per your requirement, this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/13107765/5567009

Comment: @NigamPatro Sorry for the late reply, it works fine on Kitkat but when i was running on Lollipop the star stretched smaller and just one star remaining. I update my question with the picture. On Android Kitkat device it works fine with 5 star and the style. The problem is when running on Android Lollipop device.