# Android RatingBar vector icon is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

I have a `layout` where I want to show `RatingBar` for user. I'm using my own custom icons instead of default stars. My Problem is that the icons are on vector format and when I use them I get strange effects (see image below). It should show 5 icons but it only shows one, why is that?

[image]

When I convert my vector images to `.png` everything is fine.

[image]

I will add my code here
my icons code (in `drawable` folder) `//empty_rate.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="48"
    android:viewportHeight="48"
    android:width="8dp"
    android:height="8dp">
    <group
        android:translateX="117"
        android:translateY="-118.5">
        <path
            android:pathData="M-93 122.5c-11 0 -20 9 -20 20 0 11 9 20 20 20 11 0 20 -9 20 -20 0 -11.1 -9 -20 -20 -20zm0 36c-8.8 0 -16 -7.2 -16 -16 0 -8.8 7.2 -16 16 -16 8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16 0 8.8 -7.2 16 -16 16z"
            android:fillColor="#076127" />
    </group>
</vector>

//middle_rate.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="48"
    android:viewportHeight="48"
    android:width="4dp"
    android:height="4dp">
    <group
        android:translateX="117"
        android:translateY="-118.5">
        <path
            android:pathData="M-93 122.5c-11 0 -20 9 -20 20 0 11 9 20 20 20 11 0 20 -9 20 -20 0 -11.1 -9 -20 -20 -20zm0 36c-8.8 0 -16 -7.2 -16 -16 0 -8.8 7.2 -16 16 -16 8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16 0 8.8 -7.2 16 -16 16z"
            android:fillColor="#076127" />
        <path
            android:pathData="M-105.2 142.5c0 -6.7 5.4 -12.2 12.2 -12.2l0 24.3c-6.7 0 -12.2 -5.4 -12.2 -12.1z"
            android:fillColor="#076127" />
    </group>
</vector>

//full_rate.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="48"
    android:viewportHeight="48"
    android:width="8dp"
    android:height="8dp">
    <group
        android:translateX="117"
        android:translateY="-118.5">
        <path
            android:pathData="M-93 122.5c-11 0 -20 9 -20 20 0 11 9 20 20 20 11 0 20 -9 20 -20 0 -11.1 -9 -20 -20 -20zm0 36c-8.8 0 -16 -7.2 -16 -16 0 -8.8 7.2 -16 16 -16 8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16 0 8.8 -7.2 16 -16 16z"
            android:fillColor="#076127" />
        <path
            android:pathData="M-80.8 142.5a12.2 12.2 0 0 1 -12.2 12.2 12.2 12.2 0 0 1 -12.2 -12.2 12.2 12.2 0 0 1 12.2 -12.2 12.2 12.2 0 0 1 12.2 12.2z"
            android:fillColor="#076127" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

here's my `layout` for `RatingBar`

```
<RatingBar
                android:isIndicator="true"
                style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/rate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="5"/>
```

Here's my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_ratingbar_selector</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">24dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">24dip</item>
    </style>
```

and here's my `custom_ratingbar_selector.xml` in (`drawable` folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/empty_rate" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/middle_rate" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/full_rate" />
</layer-list>
```

So what's wrong? How to solve the problem?

Comment: Check this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001823/ratingbar-custom-vector-drawables-superimposing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001823/ratingbar-custom-vector-drawables-superimposing)

Comment: @David any luck yet? i m facing a same situation right now.

Comment: @David Have you solved this?

Answer (score -1):

**Vector drawables backward compatibility solution**

To support vector drawable and animated vector drawable on devices running platform versions lower than Android 5.0 (API level 21), `VectorDrawableCompat` and `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` are available through two support libraries: `support-vector-drawable` and `animated-vector-drawable`, respectively.

Android Studio 1.4 introduced **limited compatibility** support for vector drawables by generating **PNG files at build time**. However, the vector drawable and animated vector drawable support Libraries offer both flexibility and broad compatibility — it's a support library, so you can use it with all Android platform versions back to Android 2.1 (API level 7+). To configure your app to use vector support libraries, add the `vectorDrawables` element to your `build.gradle` file in the app module.

Use the following code snippet to configure the `vectorDrawables` element:

For Gradle Plugin 2.0+:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

For Gradle Plugin 1.5 or below:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Stops the Gradle plugin’s automatic rasterization of vectors
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  // Flag notifies aapt to keep the attribute IDs around
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think you are not using a lower API level than 21 (because it's fixed by now), but if someone is still facing that solution because he needs a lower API, here you go.
This is the right technical solution even the question is deprecated. Cheers!