# How to make precise rating bar in Android?

Tags: android

I need to make precise rating bar with 5 stars, but when i have something like 2.7 rating i need to have 2.7 stars in white the others in grey. I was thinking something with the seeker bar. I added 5 stars and can easily make 4 grey when I have rating 1, but not sure how to make them partially colored.

[image]

I have something like this now :

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            setStars(i);
        }

 private void setStars(int stars){
    switch (stars){
        case 0:
            star1.setVisibility(GONE);
            star2.setVisibility(GONE);
            star3.setVisibility(GONE);
            star4.setVisibility(GONE);
            star5.setVisibility(GONE);
            break;
case 2:
            star1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            star2.setVisibility(GONE);
            star3.setVisibility(GONE);
            star4.setVisibility(GONE);
            star5.setVisibility(GONE);
            break;
```

And so on but I need it to be precise. I know i can probably make 10 states of the star for 1/10, 2/10 filled etc but that will be too much work.

Comment: Add the code, please so that people might figure where it can be improved

Comment: It will help you : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-rating-bar-example

Comment: I know Android have RatingBar but it's ugly and not easy to modify. And it's not doing what I want you can't have 3.7 or 3.8 rating there. That's why I have to come up with something custom. I can't even find a good library and there is one for almost everything :/

Comment: @STARGATEBG try my solution bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.1"
        android:rating="2.7" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks ... I had no idea there is stepSize. Now the only thing left is can I make them smaller and use custom drawables and colors?

Answer (score 3):

To reduce size and change stepSize you can do something like this

```
<RatingBar
android:id="@+id/rating"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:numStars="5"
android:stepSize="0.1"
style = "?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"/>
```

And to style your rating bar you can see this link [Styling Rating Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)