# Android Rating bar displays only one star

Tags: android, android-actionbar, ratingbar

I have created custom style for **RatingBar** and when I apply my style to rating bar, it shows only one star, and in properties of **RatingBar**, I've define the size of the start which 5 as well, but on run time it displays only one star.
Note:I am using **ActionbarActivity**, in that I am displaying **RatingBar**, but when I use only **Activity** class, it displays 5 star and the theme is also applied on that. 
So Please help me out from this issue.

Comment: post your code here!! What you have done!!

Comment: <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        style="@style/myRatingBar"/>

Comment: <style name="myRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_custom_bar</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">22dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">22dip</item>
 </style>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_blank"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_blank"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_filled"/>

</layer-list>

Comment: myRatingBar Your style post? here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android

Comment: Hey borther, my above code is working very well on Activity class but it not works on ActionBarActivity Class

Comment: you need to use a Theme.AppCompat

Answer (score 13):

check if you are using Vector Drawable which is causing this issue. So to work with it try to replace Vector Drawable with png image in the drawable folder and see the magic it work.

you are using Vector Drawable with layer-list so your Vector Drawable image is fit to the whole layout try to replace it with png which will solve your problem.

Comment: how to passed 2 hours on a vector issue :') thanks budd

Comment: I hope that it's useful

Answer (score -1):

Try this in XML:

```
<RatingBar
   android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
   style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:rating="3.5" />
```