# How to change the color of non-progress of rating bar in android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, ratingbar

I am using a rating bar in my android application and am facing a problem. I have set the rating bar color to green and want it so if the rating is 3, than 3 stars are green and the last two are invisible. Right now if the rating is 3 then the first three are green and the next two are a lighter shade of green. Like this:

[image]

How can I change it so the if the rating is three then the last two stars are invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly a duplicate but I think you might be looking for something like this

[How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

Because you need to change the drawable used to display when the star is "off" in order to make it "invisible". AFAIK Android doesn't give you currently a way to hide the off-stars.