# Custom RatingBar not showing more than 1 star

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, ratingbar

I have implemented a custom rating bar from [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800686/5747134) which isn't showing more than one star even if I set **numStars** to 5 or any other number

Here is the Code.

I'm using vector drawables for images.

RatingBar in **main_activity.xml**

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBarValue"
        style="@style/Fuel_Indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:max="5" />
```

**Fuel_Indicator** style in styles.

```
<style name="Fuel_Indicator" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/fuel_bar_full</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/fuel_bar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">23dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">25dip</item>
</style>
```

The **fuel_bar_full.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/fuel_bar_empty" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/fuel_bar_empty" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/fuel_bar_filled" />
```

**fuel_bar_empty.xml**

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_empty" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_empty" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_empty" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_empty" />
</selector>
```

**fuel_bar_filled.xml**

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_full" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_full" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_full" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_full" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your implementation is perfect But you are using `Vector Drawable` which is causing this issue. So to work with it try to replace `Vector Drawable` with `png` image in the drawable folder and see the magic it work.

you are using `Vector Drawable` with `layer-list` so your `Vector Drawable` image is fit to the whole layout try to replace it with `png` which will solve your problem.

Comment: why you think that he uses `SVG`?

Comment: @VladMatvienko because OP has write in the question. and sorry it is `Vector Drawable`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.I wonder what the problem is with Vector Drawable.

Comment: @DilipAti glad to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really the problem because of vector drawable

Comment: Here's the bug report for vectors not working with RatingBar views:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37074370

It was resolved as "Intended Behaviour", so the only supported option is using rendered images

Comment: Any tools to generate .png from vector drawables? (svg)

Comment: I am either using shape drawables or PNGs instead of vector drawables but still show only 1 star. The rest is the same. Guide, please?