# How to Change Image of Rating Bar from Server

Tags: android, ratingbar

I do have read how to make custom rating bar from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android). But I want to make rating bar that retrieve image from the server.

Does it possible ? How ?

Comment: Do you need to change image color or need to change image itself  ?

Comment: Just change the image itself i think. Because i will prepare 2 images from the server if it is possible

Comment: Is your **2 images** from the server meant to be change dynamically all the time  ?

Comment: @Nikhil yes it is

Answer (score 1):

it may be not the exact but definitely serve for your purpose with slight add on codes .

[image: A sample rating bar using drawable]

Here is the sample code

```
RatingBar mRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
mRatingBar.setStarEmptyDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.star_empty));
mRatingBar.setStarHalfDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.star_half));
mRatingBar.setStarFillDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.star_full));
mRatingBar.setStarCount(5);
mRatingBar.setStar(2.5f);
mRatingBar.halfStar(true);
mRatingBar.setmClickable(true);
mRatingBar.setStarImageWidth(120f);
mRatingBar.setStarImageHeight(60f);
mRatingBar.setImagePadding(35);
mRatingBar.setOnRatingChangeListener(
        new RatingBar.OnRatingChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChange(float RatingCount) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "the fill star is" + RatingCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
);
```

You can use your own image from server in **setStars** . All you need to do is to convert your image from server into a drawable

Here is the gradle

```
  compile 'com.hedgehog.ratingbar:app:1.1.2'
```

For a detailed explanation and updated version use this [github-link](https://github.com/hedge-hog/RatingBar)

*Please give it a try and let me know your comments*

Answer (score 0):

As you have referred the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800686/5476209), If that is your way then it's not possible cause you can not put a file in a Drawable folder at runtime, as **R.java** file is generated at compile time.