# How do we change Rating Bar Star icon with some other icon in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to change my default Rating bar Star(*) icon to another icon.
Can anybody help me out..

**My Code: XML**

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    style="@style/foodRatingBar"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:numStars="4" />
```

**Styles.xml:**

```
 <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">23dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">25dip</item>
</style>
```

**Selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_gray"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_gray"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fuel_color"/>

</layer-list>
```

**But outPut is:**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5800686/7320259 try this

Comment: I have tried that one ..it's not working at all..@Zaki Pathan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

Just add below two snippets and you are done:

```
<style name="customRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_image1</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/custom_image2</item>
</style>
```

and Use above style in your xml where rating bar is used:

```
<RatingBar style="@style/customRatingBar" ... />
```

Add replace your Rating bar code with this and check if it is showing in preview?

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/customRatingBar"
/>
```

Comment: I tried the same but the output is coming like above image which is in  my Question@Kaushik Kajavadara

Comment: just make new xml and add components one by one checking preview of xml. And use different drawable custom image.

Answer (score -2):

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="@style/foodRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="5"
    android:transformPivotX="0dp"
    android:transformPivotY="0dp"
    android:isIndicator="false"/>
```

try this