# RatingBar with star color depending on number of stars

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, ratingbar

Using Android RatingBar, I want the ratings stars to have the following colors (all stars the same color per rating):

- One star: red
- Two stars: yellow
- Three stars: blue
- Four stars: green
- Five stars: dark green

This is my code:

```
RatingBar rateDoctor;

rateDoctor = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rateDoctor);

rateDoctor.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {


    }
});
```

And my XML:

```
<RatingBar android:id="@+id/rateDoctor" android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numStars="5" android:stepSize="1.0" />
```

Comment: please share your xml

Comment: <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rateDoctor"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
             />

Comment: I have reformulated your question, edited the title and added the XML from your comment. You should [edit] it yourself and add an actual question, as there isn't one currently!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

References :
[How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

```
 <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_selector"
    android:numStars="8"
    android:stepSize="0.2"
    android:rating="3.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(ratingbar.getRating()<=1)
{
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar
                .getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for filled stars
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.hal_selected),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for half filled stars
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.no_selected),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```