# setNumStars and setRating does not work in custom RatingBar

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with seting a custom `ratingBar` in Java. The problem is that `setNumStars` and `setRating` are not working. I just get one star on the screen which is fully marked although I've set the rate to 0.0f.

Here's the code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

chapter1 = new Chapter(this);
android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels , metrics.heightPixels);
myLayout.addView(chapter1, layoutParam);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(this);
        ratingBar.setProgressDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.custom_ratingbar_menu, null));
        ratingBar.setNumStars(3);
        ratingBar.setRating(0.0f);
        layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels / 6 , metrics.heightPixels / 32);
        layoutParam.setMargins(70 + chapter1.getLeft() + wSize * j, 50 + chapter1.getTop() + hSize * i + (metrics.heightPixels / 6), 0, 0);
        myLayout.addView(ratingBar, layoutParam);
    }
}
```

And we have used the accepted answer in [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android) for `custom_ratingarbar_menu`

Here's `custom_ratingbar_menu` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/customm_empty_menu" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/customm_empty_menu" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_full_menu" />
</layer-list>
```

And it's `customm_empty_menu` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/stars_off_menu" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/stars_off_menu" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/stars_off_menu" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/stars_off_menu" />

</selector>
```

And this is `custom_full_menu` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/stars_on_menu" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/stars_on_menu" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/stars_on_menu" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/stars_on_menu" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android

Comment: Also post your `custom_ratingbar_menu` file for rating issue

Comment: @Rehan done...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**
There is some problem with setting the progress drawable in code. Your drawables work when used in XML. The problem seems to revolve around setting the appropriate attributes. If I get time, I can look into this further or maybe someone else has an idea. (Check your XML, there is a typo: "customm" instead of "custom". I have corrected it below.)

*(For API level 21 and above, you could do the following:*

In MainActivity.java:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(this, null, 0, R.style.myRatingBar);
```

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="myRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_ratingbar_menu</item>
</style>
```

But this is not a general solution, so I prefer the following.)

In the meantime, you can accomplish what you want by inflating a `RatingBar` from XML and adding it to your layout instead of doing `new RatingBar(this)`. In this way, you can make use of the attributes in the XML file. This fixes your issue.

Define an XML layout file that contains just a rating bar as follows:

**rating_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RatingBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/modelRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_menu" />
```

The drawable files are much as you defined them. I use a different icon since I did not have access to yours:

**custom_ratingbar_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_empty_menu" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_empty_menu" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_full_menu">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**custom_empty_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_off" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_off" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_off" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_off" />

</selector>
```

**custom_full_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_on" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_on" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_on" />

    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_on" />
</selector>
```

Finally, the main activity's `onCreate()`:

**MainActivity#onCreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(myLayout);
    // Your loop would go here...
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.rating_bar, myLayout, false);
    myLayout.addView(ratingBar);
    ratingBar.setNumStars(5);
    ratingBar.setStepSize(0.5f);
    ratingBar.setRating(2.0f);
}
```

---

**Old answer, but still holds.**

From the [documentation for RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html):

> The number of stars set (via setNumStars(int) or in an XML layout) will be shown when the layout width is set to `wrap_content` (if another layout width is set, the results may be unpredictable).

You are doing the following. (The width and height are not `wrap_content`.)

```
layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels / 6 , metrics.heightPixels / 32);
myLayout.addView(ratingBar, layoutParam);
```

Doing the following, instead, may get you what you want, or at least, get you the number of stars you want.

```
layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myLayout.addView(ratingBar, layoutParam);
```

I suggest that you forego the progress drawable for the time being and get the number of stars and rating right then introduce the drawable.

If this doesn't work, can you post `custom_ratingbar_menu`?

Comment: Then what if you want to apply a custom layout for the RatingBar?

Comment: @Cheticamp when I can use LayoutParams? I need it for set margins

Comment: @AryaSadeghi You can set the margins like you did before. If they are static, you can also set them in the XML for `RatingBar`. btw, I hope that the image you are using for `RatingBar` is not an XML drawable but a png or the like. I was unable to get the XML drawable to work.