# Custom RatingBar color bleed issue

Tags: android, drawable, ratingbar

I am facing a strange problem with my custom RatingBar drawable. My images of drawables are stretched as you can see in the image.

[image]

I don't know what is the issue. I tried different solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android) but none of them helped me.

Here is my rating bar xml code

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_custom"
    android:rating="4"
    android:stepSize="1" />
```

here is drawable xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_filled" />

</layer-list>
```

And these are 2 images star_empty and star_filled

[image][image]

Comment: It seems your drawables have a problem on the lower row of pixels. In specific, it seems that 2 pixels are touching the lower border.

Comment: @KlingKlang what to do now?

Comment: What about adding an empty (full transparency) line to the bottom of both your images?

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: @KlingKlang no. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Weird. It's the only thing I can think about a possible cause, as of now.