# How can I change android rating widget stars to numbers?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

How Can I make it show numbers instead of stars?
I want my android rating widget to look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxE0D.jpg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)